# How to calculate date difference for all IDs in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How can I do to check if the difference between date 1 and date 2 for every ID is more than 6 months? Let me illustrate with an example.

So I have a table like this one:

```
+----+---------+
| ID |   Y-M   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 2017-01 |
|  1 | 2017-02 |
|  1 | 2017-10 |
|  2 | 2017-04 |
|  2 | 2017-06 |
|  3 | 2017-06 |
|  4 | 2017-07 |
+----+---------+
```

And I want to add a third column that says yes if the difference between the first one and the second one is more than 6months. I want to say yes only on the first one. In case there is no date to compare with, then it would be also a yes. Anyway, this would be the final result:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| ID |   Y-M   | Difference |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | 2017-01 | No         |
|  1 | 2017-02 | Yes        |
|  1 | 2017-10 | Yes        |
|  2 | 2017-04 | Yes        |
|  2 | 2017-11 | No         |
|  2 | 2017-12 | Yes        |
|  3 | 2017-06 | Yes        |
|  4 | 2017-07 | Yes        |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? You can [edit] and add a tag for it.

Comment: I do not understand the close votes on this question.  It seems like a very reasonable question (although it has been edited).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lead()` and some date arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(ym) over (partition by id order by ym) < dateadd(month, 6, ym)
             then 'No' else 'Yes'
        end) as difference
from t;
```

Comment: This is the right answer that solves the problem. Thank you